# Converting simple C++ code to C# automatically

Tags: c#, c++, code-translation

I have a file in C++ containing constant definitions, I want to use the same definitions in a C# project. Since both projects are part of a bigger project, I want if there is a change (addition/deletion) in the C++ file it should get reflected in corresponding C# file too. I want to keep the 2 files in sync. I was wondering if there is a script/tool to do this.

A reverse solution (C#-->C++) would also work.

Clarification:

Currently the code is:

```
//C++ 
    struct Colors{ 
         static const int Red = 100; //Custom Values are important 
         static const int Green = 101; } 
//C#

public enum Color{ Red = 100; Green =101; }
```

Now I want to have a single file so that any changes in C++ are reflected in C# (or other way around) so that I can have a single file across the projects for these constants.

As you see, I want to map bunch of constants defined in a struct in C++ to a enum in C#. I want to make no/minimal changes in above expected definitions as there is other code dependent (in both projects) on the above structures (but might do it, if there's not a good way of accomplishing this in the current format)

Comment: What kinds of constants? Most importantly, what data types are involved? A short sample snippet would be handy as well.

Comment: Great that you asked! Currently the code is:

//C++
struct Colors{
static const int Red = 100; //Custom Values are important
static const int Green = 101; 
}

From the above I want to get in C#:
public enum Color{
Red =  100;
Green =101;
}

As you see, I want to map bunch of constants defined in a struct in C++ to a enum in C#. I want to make no/minimal changes in above expected definitions as there is other code dependent (in both projects) on the above structures (but might do it, if there's not a good way of accomplishing this in the current format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wont find a script... You should have your own script to do this. Otherwise MACROs are the best fit...

If you have a script then you can create a rule in your makefile that will automatically run this script whenever you build your project.

Comment: ohh i actually ment PreProcessor directives and not MACROs. "MACRO" is probably more attached to c++ in this context

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you take the constants file and package it seperately as an assembly something like App.Constants.dll and have both C# and c++ projects reference them? In this way, you can make change in one place. Have project based references to make it easy in Visual Studio.

Comment: This would require the use of managed C++ (which isn't really C++ at all), surely?

Comment: @bdonlan I am sure you can use unmanaged c++ as well. Are you sure?

Comment: You should be able to pInvoke things from a normal C++ library, much like you would existing windows libraries that don't already have a managed wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming plain integer constants and such, it should be possible to reuse the same source file by using preprocessor creatively. Something like this:

```
#if CSHARP
public class Constants {
#else
#  define public
#endif

// Easy stuff
public const int FOO = 1;
public const int BAR = 2;

// Enums can be done too, but you have to handle the comma
public enum Color { COLOR_RED, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLUE }
#if !CSHARP
;
#endif

#if CSHARP
}
#else
#  undef public
#endif
```

You might need typedefs for some types so that their names match (e.g. `typedef unsigned int uint`).

Then you compile code as part of your C# project with `/define:CSHARP`, and also `#include` it into some C++ header with no additional defines.

Comment: This is a great way, but would lead to really messy code in my particular case.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to create a managed C++ library that contains the constants and enums in a format that is reusable in both unmanaged C++ and C#.

Managed version:

```
//managed.cpp
#define MAKECONST(name, value) public const int ##name = ##value; 

public enum class FruitType
{
    #include "FruitType.h"
};

pubilc ref class Constants {
   #include "const.h"
};
```

Unmanaged version:

```
//unmanaged.cpp
#define MAKECONST(name, value) const int ##name = ##value;

enum FruitType
{
    #include "FruitType.h"
};

#include "const.h"
```

The actual enum definitions:

```
//FruitType.h
Apple = 1,
Banana,
Lychee
```

The consts file:

```
//consts.h
MAKECONST(NumFruitInABowl, 3)
MAKECONST(NumBowls, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

An automated method of doing this it to use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to convert your C++ code to C#.